# ReSharper 7 autocomplete incorrectly displays "No suggestions" after typing "this."

Tags: c#, autocomplete, resharper, resharper-7.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP 1 w/ .NET 4.0 and I just upgraded to ReSharper 7.  Since upgrading, when I type "this.", Resharper autocomplete *always* displays "No suggestions" as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

If I type ctrl+space at this point, it will come up with suggestions.  I can also get suggestions if I hit escape (exit autocomplete) and then delete and re-type the dot.  Either way, functioning autocomplete looks like this:

[image]

I'd really, really like autocomplete to work automatically as soon as I type "this."; can you help?

I've tried suspending and unsuspending ReSharper, restarting Visual Studio, restarting Visual Studio with ReSharper suspended, and combing the ReSharper autocomplete options.  I've tried clearing the ReSharper cache, suspending ReSharper, and *then* restarting Visual Studio.  It doesn't appear to be related to these things in a way that I can see.

I've also tried typing "this." very slowly and the behavior did not change; it doesn't appear to be a race condition.  Visual Studio itself auto-completes correctly but using ReSharper autocomplete always has this problem.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give!

**Update**: After restarting Visual Studio again, the autocomplete selections did appear correctly *once* if I typed "this." before VS / ReSharper seemed to fully load (it hiccuped while I typed and when it recovered, the autocomplete was correct).  Subsequent attempts reverted to the undesirable behavior.

This is really weird.  I've filed an issue with JetBrains here:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-330185

Comment: FWIW, I have used the same setup as you and don't see this issue. Might be worth reinstalling. Are you sure that the *no suggestions* text is coming from R# and now VS?

Comment: Not really on-topic for this site. Suggest you contact Jetbrains support.

Comment: @Drew, I just tried reinstalling and the problem persists.  As for the text itself, I believe I covered that in the question.  When I disable ReSharper, the VS Intellisense does what I expect.  When I re-enable ReSharper, the problem returns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same setup and it works. Your issue can be caused by:

- a defective ReSharper installation
- additional plugins that interfere with the Resharper IntelliSense
- your computer is just a bit to slow and doesn't build the list fast enough

Edit:
I would reinstall resharper (completly remove it - don't repair) and try again.

Comment: I've tried completely re-installing now.  I've also uninstalled / disabled all extensions except the NuGet package manager.  The problem persists.  Thanks for your suggestions.  Since it seems to be working for everybody else, I'll contact JetBrains directly.

Comment: Yes - this might help. It might be a .Net issue too. Did you install all patches?

Answer (score 0):

You may disable ResharperIntellisense or limit it from Resharper->Options->Intellisense->General. I think it is beacause my computer is too slow also or a problem with VS2010.